# Definition of cartesian product when the index set is finite

Tags: products, cross-product

Let $\{A_j | j\in J\}$ be be a family of sets. By definition,

$$\prod_{j\in J} A_j = \{f: J \to \cup_{j\in J} A_j | f(j) \in A_j  \}.$$

However, when we are given two sets, say $G,H$, we are not given any index set, what should we supposed to choose as our index set ?

Even we are expected to choose, say $J = \{1,2\}$, then why $G\times H \not = H\times G$ ? I mean after all, $J$ is just a **set**, so we cannot put any ordering relation on $J$, which means that as long as $f(1) \in G$ and $f(2) \in H$, $f:J \to G \cup H$ is the same, hence we should have 
$$G\times H = H\times G.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take $\{H,G\}$ as your index set; and then the order does indeed no longer matter: a typical element of the product looks like $\bigl\{\langle G,x\rangle,\langle H,y\rangle\bigr\}$, which is equal to $\bigl\{\langle H,y\rangle,\langle G,x\rangle\bigr\}$.

In the paragraph above is the definition of $\prod\{G,H\}$. If one wants to *define* $G\times H$ to be $\prod\{G,H\}$ then one will have to accept that $G\times H=H\times G$. Note that if $G=H$ the product reduces to the set $\{\langle G,x\rangle:x\in G\}$, which is not quite what you'd expect.

Using an indexed family (which is necessary if you need to repeat the same set) results in as many products as there are indexings. For example, if you want a product of two copies of $G$ and one of $H$ then you need some kind of indexing: $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$, where it matters whether $H=X_1$, $H=X_2$ or $H=X_3$. To all intents and purposes the three products are the same, except as sets.

If you want do define $G\times H$ as the product of an indexed family, say with the canonical indexing set $\{0,1\}$, then set-wise the indexing matters. Property-wise it does not.

Comment: Yeah, but you see, you say one index set, and I say a different one. Of couse, as long as the cardinalities are the same, we can form a bijection from one possible cartesian products to another. However, even that bijection depends on the person who is constructing it.

Comment: If you start out by defining the cartesian product as a set of functions as in your question then you know what $\prod\{G,H\}$ is: the set of functions as defined in my answer. If you then *define* $G\times H$ to be that product then you will have to accept that $G\times H=H\times G$. I'll expand my answer a bit.

Comment: What if $H = G$?

Comment: See the expanded answer.

Comment: Incidentally I tried to add a remark on the possibility of regarding an ordered pair (or other tuple) as a function on a set of "variable names", or "symbols", or suchlike, but it is awkward when mathematical notation becomes part of the substance of mathematics itself - and the difficulty I had in typesetting my attempted remark reflected this awkwardness! The main point was that although there is a problem when $H = G$, there is no problem in using the distinct *names* $G$ and $H$. But it's a murky area.

Answer (score 1):

If, say, $a\in G$, $a\notin H$, $b\in H$ then $(a,b)\in G\times H$ and $(b,a)\notin
H\times G$. Therefore $G\times H\ne H\times G$.

Here we interpret $(a,b)$ as the function with $1\mapsto a$ and $2\mapsto b$,
that is $\{(1,a),(2,b)\}$ as a set of ordered pairs, and similarly for
$(b,a)$.

Comment: Well, in my context, the concept of _tuple_ has no meaning. I mean I'm currently working on Category theory (as a part of graduate Algebra course), and we are given the above general definition for any cartesian product of sets.

Comment: So, somehow the above definition, when restrict it to the finite case, be compatible with what we are doing. I mean I can give same argument for a family that is given with an index set $I$.